# Proof - Find basis of all linearmaps from U to V

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, independence

I'm trying to proof that:
$\{T_{ij}\}$ is basis of L(V,U)

$A=\{u_i\}_{i=1}^m$ - basis of U vector space (U,F)

$B=\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ - basis of V vector space (V,F)

$i\in \{1,2,....n\}, j\in \{1,2,....m\} $

$ {T}_{ij}: V\to U  $ (linearmap from V to U)

$The\ linearmap \ \{T_{ij}\} \ rule: \ \ \ \ \ (\theta_i \in F)$

${T}_{ij}(\sum_{k=1}^n \theta_k \cdot v_k) = \theta_i \cdot u_j$

L(V,U) - all the linearmaps from V to U

What I did so far?

trying to proof that $\{T_{ij}\}$ is independent.
lets assume that all the linear combination equals to zero.
${T}_{ij}(\sum_{k=1}^n \theta_k \cdot v_k) =\sum_{k=1}^n  {T}_{ij}(\theta_k \cdot v_k) = \theta_i \cdot u_j = 0$

$\Rightarrow \{\theta_i\}_{i=1}^n = 0 $(because A is basis and independent)

$\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n  \theta_k \cdot {T}_{ij}( v_k) = 0 $
$\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n  \theta_k \cdot {T}_{ij}( v_k) = 0 $

$\Rightarrow \{T_{ij}\}$ is independent group.

I have feeling that I wrong somewhere...
I searched a lot and I didnt found anything...

Comment: Easier to think in terms of matrices. Consider the matrix with $1$ in the $(i,j)$ position and $0$ elsewhere. These matrices form a basis for the space of all $n \times n$ matrices.

Comment: I already saw proof with representation matrix.
Im trying to solve it with the definition of linear independent.